# How can I customize the appearence of the node in node editor

Tags: python

I want to change the node in node editor to triangle shape, or any other shape I want, not a quad shape node as default, and the port on the node is a dot, I need also to change it to some other shape.

Can you suggest me of a practical approach to achieve this? Is this possible to use the Python api or should I go to the blender core?

Comment: You'll have to build your own Blender.

Comment: Are you saying a blender of "my" version

Comment: To answer the question, it's not possible with the Python API and you'll have to mess with the source code in C / C++